Is it legal/ethical to use social media posts from news outlets for academic research?
I am planning a university research project in which I intend to collect and analyze publicly available social media posts made by news outlets. I plan to gather this data manually, without using automated scraping tools. The data gathered would include the title of the news post, the short description, the date of the post, the number of comments and reactions (likes, shares, etc.). The main goal of the project is to identify which topics are discussed by which news networks and potentially detect bias. Since news outlets hold copyrights on their content, could this type of data be used for academic research in a way that is legal and ethical?

To clarify, these are posts made by the organizations, not by individuals posting on their sites. Correct? In particular, even if Musk posts on X that is by him as an individual, not as X, the corporate entity.

Yes, these posts are made on the page of the news outlet, not on some particular person's page.

You don't say if you are employed or affiliated with an institution in the US. If so, you should consult with your institution's Institutional Review Board. Staff can advise you if you need to get a formal review or not. Since this is public information and there is no contact with human subjects, this should be exempt. An IRB can provide you a statement that the research is exempt.

First, IANAL, and you should probably consult the legal department at your organization, but what you describe seems fine, within limits.
Note that copyright doesn't imply that you can't use what is written and copyrighted, nor that you can't discuss it in publication. What the law, generally (though it differs in some places) restricts is republication except for limited excerpts. Moreover, in most jurisdictions, the law is a bit more flexible in this for education and research than for other uses.
But, titles, usage statistics, dates, your own descriptions, and similar things should be fine.
I doubt that even automated collection would raise any issues. What would, is what you write and how much you excerpt from the writings of others. Scraping user provided comments/posts with automated processes raises different issues, of course, but you don't propose that.
Note that "copyright" is literally rights about copying. In particular copyright protects expression, not facts.
Ethically, beyond copyright, you also need to avoid plagiarism in writings, but I don't see that issue arising in anything you have said here.
And, as I raised in comments, reposting/republishing the comments of individuals, on social media sites is a different issue and would probably require the approval of an ethical board (IRB). This would be an especially serious issue if those individuals were identified/identifiable.

The terms of conditions of the social media service(s) in question may also impose restrictions, and likely do when it comes to automated collection.

@Anyon, yes, that is probably recent and a result of AI firms scraping content for reuse in their large language models. But there doesn't seem to be the same intent here, but only statistical data gathering. Consult a lawyer. And, it isn't the user provided content that would be gathered, but only corporate provided information.

@Anyon, I'd also make the distinction, that the OP doesn't intend to scrape data from within such sites, but only data that they publish about themselves. That is quite different. Oddly, X permits such scraping of data, explicitly. Meta does not.

In Australia, this would fall under the broad category of "research involving human subjects", and would need ethics approval. You'd likely get that approval, but you should still make sure you get it.

And where would one apply to get this approval?

It will depend on your institution. If it is a university project, you presumably have an advisor. This would be a question for them.
